# VBA: problems with defining variables in function if Option Explicit is used

Tags: vba, excel, basic

I have the following problem:

`Option Explicit` is used.

the code

```
Function myFun( myVar as Double) as double
    myVar = myVar + 1
end function
```

throws an error that `myVar` is not defined

however, if I add the line `Dim myVar as Double` it says that the variable is declared twice.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Clearly this is not code that you actually tried.  Please edit your question and clarify what you expect this function to return and how that return value is supposed to be useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring it twice, if you add `Dim myVar as Double` in the function `myFun`. The first time is with that line and the second line is in the parameters here:

```
Function myFun( myVar as Double) as double
```

That does not have anything to do with `Option Explicit`, you are not allowed to declare two variables with the same name in the same scope.

---

I suppose your code looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    'dim myVar as double (uncomment to avoid the error)
    myVar = 5
    Debug.Print myFun(myVar)

End Sub

Function myFun(myVar As Double) As Double
    myVar = myVar + 1
End Function
```

In order to avoid the "Not declared error", you should declare `myVar` in the `Sub TestMe` and not in the `myFun` function.

Comment: yes, exactly, that's what my first version of the code looks like

but, if I call the function, it throws an error saying that myVar is not defined at all?

Comment: @Florian - see the edit and declare in the Sub.

Comment: ok, thanks very much for your help! That is really cumbersome. Is it correct tot say then that I need to use the same variable name in any function I write as it is declared in the sub?

Comment: No, the variable name you use in the `TestMe` sub can be anything.  `AnotherVariableName=5:  Debug.Print myFun(AnotherVariableName)` would still work.  The `myVar` variable in the `myFun` function would then just hold a reference to the `AnotherVariableName` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment to Vityata's question, let me try a slightly different way of explaining things.

You need to think about the **Scope** of the variable.

Consider that you have two separate procedures:

**Procedure 1**

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim myVar As Double
    myVar = 5
    Debug.Print myFun(myVar)
End Sub
```

**Procedure 2**

```
Function myFun(myVar As Double) As Double
    myFun = myVar + 1
End Function
```

- The module has `Option Explicit` at the top
- Your variables are defined within each procedure

  - The scope of the variable is the procedure
- Therefore, each variable needs to be declared within each procedure.
- Even though they have the same names, since the scope of the variable is only within the procedure, they are not the same variables.

If you want to declare a variable, and have it be the same variable in more than one procedure, you need to declare it a module level (for example).

```
Option Explicit
Public myVar As Double

Public Sub TestMe()
    myVar = 5
    myFun myVar
    Debug.Print myVar
End Sub

Function myFun(myVar) As Double
    myVar = myVar + 1
End Function
```

Note also in the two different modules, the `Function` and the call to the function are subtly different.

As an aside, declaring the variable with the `Public` keyword at the module level will make it visible to all procedures within the `Project`.  Declaring it with the `Private` keyword will make it visible to all procedures in that `Module`.

Comment: thank you very much! I understood everything I need now. This was very helpful