# (expected expression) vba error

Tags: vba, excel

so basically my code goes like this:

```
Sub clor2()

For j = 0 To 10    
  For i = 0 To 10    
  if i mod = 0 and and j mod=0 then    
    [D2].Offset(j, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37       
 Else    
[D2].Offset(j, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 36    
End If        
  Next i    
  Next j        
End Sub
```

Comment: You have and in there twice. Vityata has the correct answer below.  I just wanted to explain what they did to fix it.

Comment: ya just saw it,thanks.

Comment: also not modding by anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mod` operator is used like this `5 mod 2 = 1` and `6 mod 2 = 0`.[VBA equivalent to Excel's mod function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378047/vba-equivalent-to-excels-mod-function).

Thus, it should be `i Mod SomeNumber = 0` for the condition.

```
Option Explicit

Sub clor2()
    Dim j As Long, i As Long

    For j = 0 To 10
        For i = 0 To 10
            If i Mod 3 = 0 And j Mod 7 = 0 Then
                [D2].Offset(j, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
            Else
                [D2].Offset(j, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
            End If
        Next i
    Next j    

End Sub
```

`Option Explicit` is also a good practice in VBA - thus your variables `i` and `j` should be declared. - [VBA: problems with defining variables in function if Option Explicit is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930209/vba-problems-with-defining-variables-in-function-if-option-explicit-is-used)

Comment: what was wrong with my code?i dont see any diff,but urs worked

Comment: You had the word And in there twice after if I Mod = 3

Comment: @tehcoder - I have updated. In general, whenever looking for a difference between two similar texts, you can use some difference checker. See this one online - https://www.diffchecker.com/